# Laravel How do I access differents models through a single models with polymorphic relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to develop an app where one can make his own program with different activities. So far I have 3 tables, the first one is the program table :

```
// Program table
id - integer
title - string
```

Then I have a program_activities table

```
// Program_Activities Table
id - integer
program_id - integer
activity_id - integer
activity_type - string
```

And then I have all my different activities (Sightseeing, Camping, etc...)

How can I access all activities through the Program model? Something like this

```php
// Program.php

Class Program extends Model
{
    [...]

    public function activities()
    {
        // retrurn all activities
    }
}
```

So that `$session->activities` would list me all the activities from that session?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does each activity type (Sightseeing, Camping etc) its own Model? To me it feels like this should have a pivot table instead and be a belongsToMany relationship.

Comment: Indeed each Activity has it's own model.

Comment: I agree with @GeorgeHanson, `activities()` should return `$this->belongsToMany('App\Activity')`. And when you'll do `$program->activities`, you should get all activities linked to the program.

Comment: However, your pivot table's name should be `activity_program`, not the inverse.

Comment: @KévinBibollet shouldn't it be hasMany? Since each session can have many activities? And the problem is that I don't have any "Activity" Model... since each Activity can be different... It would be `$this->hasMany('App\Camping')`. And then what happen to Sightseeing for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "*session*"? And yeah, a program can have many activities, but an activity can be associated to many programs.

Comment: So you have a model and a table for each activity?

Comment: Sorry, I meant program instead of session. And yes, each type of activity has its own model, relations and table (that I didn't put for simplification, but yes, each activity is a model on it's own, and I do have a lot of them (around 15 different activities). So writing down each relation could be quite long. That's why I wanted to use a polymorphic relationship so it could just retrieve the correct model directly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I "kinda" resolved my problem, but I don't really think it's good practice nor do I think it's optimal. Nontheless, here's my solution. If somebody find a better way, please show me.

```php
// Program.php

    [...]

    /**
     * Get the activities of the program.
     */
    public function activities()
    {
        $program_activities = $this->hasMany('App\ProgramActivity')->get();
        $activities = [];
        foreach ($program_activities as $program_activity){
            $className = $program_activity->activity_type;
            $activity = $className::find($program_activity->activity_id);

            $activities[] = $activity;
        }
        $activities = collect($activities);
        return $activities;
    }
```

That way, when I do `$program->activities()`, I do get all the activities of the program.

Even though I think there is a better way to do this, or I think Laravel might cover this with one of it's many relations, I didn't found any. If you have a better answer, then please post it =)